# Next/Prev buttons onClick scroll to next and previous <td>'s

Tags: javascript, button, scroll, jquery-selectors

I'm still learning JavaScript and need some help. I am making next and previous buttons that cause a scroll to the next or previous `<td>`'s on the page. I'm trying to implement this to the existing structure of a virb site. 
the markup looks like this:

```
div id="next">next</div><div id="prev">prev</div>
<table>
<tr><td>code that includes img</td></tr>
<tr><td>code that includes img</td></tr>
<tr><td>code that includes img</td></tr>
<tr><td>code that includes img</td></tr>
<tr><td>code that includes img</td></tr>
</table>
```

Here is the script I'm working with:

```
jQuery.easing.def = "easeInOutQuad";
    $("#next").click(function (){
        //$(this).animate(function(){
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollLeft: $("td").next.offset().left
                 }, 600);
        //});

    });​
```

[​Here is the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/garretthaas/kzqVp/5/) I'm working on

Comment: Here is the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/garretthaas/kzqVp/8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following keeps track of your current item to view. You'll need a similar thig to decrement the index in your 'prev' routine.

You may also need to add a delay or an event cut-off so that multiple clicks during animation don't take the value of currentIdx above or below the range of items you have to show.

```
var currentIdx = 0;
jQuery.easing.def = "easeInOutQuad";
        $("#next").click(function (){

            //$(this).animate(function(){
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollLeft: $("td").eq(currentIdx).offset().left
                     }, 600);
                currentIdx++;     
            //});
        });
```

Comment: Thank you. I think I get it now. I changed .eq(currentIdx) to .eq(currentIdx + 1) because there was a click that returned the first item. It worked when I created the decremented bit of code as well. Here is the JSFiddle with the updated code... See any problems with my edits? [http://jsfiddle.net/garretthaas/kzqVp/12/](http://jsfiddle.net/garretthaas/kzqVp/12/)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
    scrollLeft: $("td").next().offset().left
```

Comment: Thank you! that worked, but only for one click. it didn't continue to the next image when I clicked next a second time. I'll do some more testing, but am still open to suggestions.