# make a div horizontally scrollable

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to make a div horizontally scrollable
this is an html example:

```
     <div class="container">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="grid grid-wr">
          <h1>Products We Offer</h1><hr>
          <div class="product-slide">
            <button id="arrows" class="next">&#8250;</button>
              <img class="product" src="" alt="">
              <img class="product" src="" alt="">
              <img class="product" src="" alt="">
              <img class="product" src="" alt="">
              <img class="product" src="" alt="">
              <img class="product" src="" alt="">
            <button id="arrows" class="prev">&#8249;</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13247297/7116394)

```
            var currentIdx = 0;
            jQuery.easing.def = "easeInOutQuad";
                $(".next").click(function (){

                    //$(this).animate(function(){
                        $('.product-slide').animate({
                            scrollLeft: $(".product").eq(currentIdx).offset().left
                             }, 600);
                        currentIdx++;
                    //});
                });
```

BUT doesn't work properly for me
I want to scroll items one by one, ore show next 5 or whatever??
The increment doesn't work
WHEN I put fixed distance ex:+=400px it works fine, I'm really getting stuck

Comment: _"doesn't work properly for me"_ means what exactly? Isn't it scrolling at all? Too little, too much?

Comment: It just move a little bit then after a second click do the scroll eventually it stops "doesn't do any further scrolling"

Comment: No, I have changed it to fit mine, this is the example

Comment: to which `td` are you referring in `$("td").eq(currentIdx)`?

Comment: this is the example not mine, I have changed the ("td") with the class I am using. It works like very tiny move the scroll as I want the it stops working

Comment: I'm a bit confused, because the js code doesn't match the html. So try to change `$("td")` to `$("img")`

Comment: I appreciate your efforts, but I already changed it with the right selector But in vain thank you so much :)

Comment: @MrGendy Could you provide a `Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example` ? Because right now, there's nothing we can do...

Comment: I edited the question, just give it a look now   thanks in advance